# How can I add favicon.ico?

Tags: html

I created a favicon from https://www.favicon.cc and replaced the existing favicon.ico to mine but it didn't change to my favicon.ico and still showing the previous icon

Code:

link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"

The location is at the same as for previous one

main.html(I am using VUE)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- favicon added -->
        <link rel="icon"      href="/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>...</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- main typescript file added -->
        <script type="module" src="/">.   </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there anymore info about your web server environment that you can post? Can you post a link to the favicon.ico file, and/or the whole html doc?

Comment: For sure, this is my main.index. I am working with VUE currently and I just replaced my icon with the one that was previously and it's in the same directory, also, the name are same too.    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- favicon added -->
    <link rel="icon"  href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- main typescript file added -->
    <script type="module" src="/"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Did you try to erase your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes, it worked when erasing browser's cache, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Browser cache clean was required

Credit: Vladimir https://stackoverflow.com/users/19636184/vladimir

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are on the right track. Are you positive the new file is in the root directory?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's the same after adding the type and yes, the directory is the same. I just changed the icon and rest is all as it is